# Different results in firebase functions when entering a route with / a that I enter without /

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

**Why when I deploy a function in firebase functions the result of entering the root of the site is different than when I just put / at the end of the path?**

What I want to say is that for example, when I try to enter the path of my function already deployed in firebase functions:

https://us-central1-nestjs.cloudfunctions.net/api

I get: Cannot GET null,

but when I just put the / at the end:

https://us-central1-nestjs.cloudfunctions.net/api/

It works well.

And it's weird because in my local environment that does not happen.

**Does anyone know what is due?**

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking:

```
https://us-central1-nestjs.cloudfunctions.net/api
```

and

```
https://us-central1-nestjs.cloudfunctions.net/api/
```

Are two total different pages. Try to think as:

```
http://www.your-domain.com/
```

and

```
http://www.your-domain.com/index.html
```

Which are also two different pages even though they display the exact same page.

And to anwer your question.

> Why when I deploy a function in firebase functions the result of entering the root of the site is different than when I just put / at the end of the path?

Because each one of those urls points to a different location. In terms of SEO (Search Engine Optimization), to make sure that Google understands both urls as a single url, you need to use [canonical URLs](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).